# Paypal - Auto Return Turned On But Not Working

Tags: php, paypal

I have gone through a lot of these questions as I am most definitely not the first. I have seen that I should use IPN to handle transaction information to keep track of the state of each transaction and I will probably set this up after I get this to work first. I need the users to come back to the site after they have finished paying. I can't leave them there. So obviously you turn on Auto Return in your Selling Preferences.

I have gone in and turned the Auto Return On, as well as provided a URL that goes back to my site but I override this in the form when I send the information off to Paypal. So my form looks like this.

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">
    <input type="hidden" value="jestewart.11@gmail.com" name="business">
    <input type="hidden" value="NA" name="item_number">
    <input type="hidden" value="30.00" name="amount">
    <input type="hidden" value="5.17" name="shipping">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="discount_amount">        
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="no_shipping">
    <input type="hidden" value="No comments" name="cn">
    <input type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://127.0.0.1/barbayq/paypalreturn.php" name="return">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
    <input type="hidden" value="US" name="lc">
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout" name="submit">
</form>
```

Pretty straightforward. Every single time I go through and test with one of my testing accounts the payments go through just fine but I get the option to return back to the page I sent through, it does not auto return.

My questions is has anyone had something similar happen to them? Also, this is wishful thinking but is there an error log in my account that says 'Hey your auto return URL sucks', or something? This seems to easy to me yet does not seem to work. I have read through question after question and every piece of documentation on this thing. If I have another feature enabled does that disable auto return?

Also I know the URL needs to be validated and properly formatted but PayPal says the URL is fine when I save it. Also is there anywhere on PayPal that says what a properly formatted page is besides this.

"As specified in the PayPal User Agreement, you must provide verbiage on the page displayed by the Return URL that

- Helps the buyer understand that the payment has been made and that the transaction has been completed.
- Explains that payment transaction details will be emailed to the buyer."

Any help here, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 127.0.0.1 as a return URL.  That's the same as "localhost" and at the point that's getting called it's running on PayPal's server, so if PayPal's server attempts to redirect back to 127.0.0.1 like you're doing here, it would be hitting itself.

You need to either use your public IP address or setup a domain (or subdomain) that hits your IP address on your test server in order to get this working.